# No sound in Phaser 3 app when using Capacitor to build for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, phaser-framework, capacitor

I have created a simple [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/phaser3) test app (in Typescript, with `rollup` to transpile) and am using [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) to convert it into an iOS app on my Mac.

This is the relevant part of the app:

```
function preload () {
    this.load.audio('boom', ['boom.mp3', 'boom.ogg', './boom-44100.ogg', './boom-44100.mp3']);
    this.load.image('wizball', './wizball.png');
}

function create () {
    const image = this.add.image(400, 300, 'wizball').setInteractive();;
    this.boom = this.sound.add('boom');
    image.on('pointerup', () => {
        this.boom.play();
    });
}
```

The app shows an image of a [wizball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizball), and if you click it, you hear "boom".

When I run it:

- With `npm run watch`, using http://localhost:10001 in a browser on my Mac, it works fine;
- By loading `index.html` in the `dist/` dir in a browser on my Mac, it works fine;
- By loading https://garion.org/soundtest-ts/ on either my Mac or my iPad, it works fine;
- But when I use Capacitor to build an iOS app in Xcode, clicking the image gives no sound at all.

These are the steps to generate the iOS app:

```
npm i
npm run watch
npx cap add ios
npx cap copy ios
npx cap open ios
```

The console log in Xcode shows the following error:

```
Error: There is no audio asset with key "boom" in the audio cache
⚡️  URL: capacitor://localhost/game.js
```

I find this strange, because the image asset can be found just fine. In the `ios/App/public/` dir, both `boom.mp3` and `wizball.png` are present.

I have put the full code, with steps to reproduce, here: https://github.com/joostvunderink/soundtest You will need node 10+ and Xcode (with at least one virtual device configured) installed to build the iOS app.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable web audio in your game config, add to bottom of your game config to be like this.

```
let game = new Phaser.Game({
  ...
  audio: {
    disableWebAudio: true
  }
});
```

Warning:

- Disable web audio will make phaser use html5 audio.
- Using html5 audio
  instead of web audio will make your game lag

Another workaround for this problem are:

1. Use external audio files, web audio still can work if you using
   audio files **not** from internal assets (I still can't find out why)
2. Using native audio/media plugin to play the audio for the phaser-capacitor app

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. I found out that only with ios platform phaser loader can't parse ArrayBuffer on sound load. That's why I load audio with simple fetch and add to phaser with scene.sound.decodeAudio.
Something like that:

```
fetch(sound.url)
  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then((response) => {
    scene.sound.decodeAudio({
      data: response,
      key: 'audioKey',
    });
  });
```

Comment: Interesting, would you mind sharing your customer loader for this please?

Comment: Added to the original answer

Comment: Did you create a custom MultiFile loader for this, one that can run during the preload as part of the normal process?